# X3D Volume Rendering using PNG file instead of NRRD file

Tags: x3d

So I was wondering if it's at all possible to use a PNG file in place of an NRRD file when rendering volume in X3D? I know there's something in the API called TextureAtlas that I think might be what I'm looking for but I can't seem to find a working example anywhere online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the X3D player I was using, that being instantplayer by instantreality, does not support the TextureAtlas node in the first place. So it appears the only player that might support the different nodes I need is X3DOM, seeing as how I was able to find an example in a slideshow online.